# Query Firestore documents by lowest number of viewcount

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query a set of 5 records from my firestore database. Every time the client successfully queries 5 records, each record's view field on the document increments by 1. I basically want all records in the database to get an equal chance to be seen on the client side so records with the lowest view value should get queried. However, the following query doesn't behave as expected as I keep getting the same set of records even though the queried records now have higher view values. Doesn't orderBy with descending set to false sort the collection to have the lowest value listed first?

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('records')
    .where('city', isEqualTo: city)
    .where('views', isGreaterThan: -1)
    .orderBy('views', descending: false)
    .limit(5)
    .get();

snapshot.docs.forEach((element) async {
  Record record =
      Record.fromMap(element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('records')
        .doc(record.recordID)
        .update({'views': FieldValue.increment(1)});
  }
}
```

[image]

Doc id and view logs after first query:

- I/flutter ( 3630): e56a4c40-40e5-11ec-9a4b-b5164e53b334
- I/flutter ( 3630): 4
- I/flutter ( 3630):    ecd328c0-40e6-11ec-a76a-cd0a98374153
- I/flutter ( 3630): 4
- I/flutter ( 3630): dc894420-40e3-11ec-a113-2d0055afb86b
- I/flutter ( 3630): 4
- I/flutter ( 3630): e3f554f0-40e4-11ec-a3ae-1f948418cef9
- I/flutter ( 3630): 4

Doc log and views 2nd query:

- I/flutter ( 3630): ecd328c0-40e6-11ec-a76a-cd0a98374153
- I/flutter ( 3630): 5
- I/flutter ( 3630): e56a4c40-40e5-11ec-9a4b-b5164e53b334
- I/flutter ( 3630): 5
- I/flutter ( 3630): dc894420-40e3-11ec-a113-2d0055afb86b
- I/flutter ( 3630): 5
- I/flutter ( 3630): e3f554f0-40e4-11ec-a3ae-1f948418cef9
- I/flutter ( 3630): 5

Comment: Nothing in your code increments the `views` field, so it's hard to say if that's going correctly. Can you edit your question to: 1) log the document ID and the `views` field value of each result, 2) show a screenshot of one of the documents returned?

Comment: Hi Frank, views increment as expected. I posted a screenshot of the firestore database.

Comment: Please also include #1 from my comment.

Comment: Updated, not sure if the edit is what you're looking for. There are documents in the database with view value of 0, 1, etc, but they are not getting queried. All of the city fields are the same, so that is not an issue.

Comment: Isn't related with compound queries in Firestore https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries ?

Comment: This compound query should work since there's only a range filter only on one field (view), while the other on city is just an equality.

Comment: Okay, just fixed it... I just removed the descending parameter after order by and it works now...not sure why the descending parameter was causing an issue

Comment: That sounds odd indeed. If I find a moment, I'll see if I can set up a repro on Dartpad.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the behavior you're describing with `.orderBy('viewcount', descending: false)` here: https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=20f3d89731f2ec97b654a67b0e8350fd. This is a collection with 5 documents, with `viewcount` values `1` through `5`.

Comment: Right, orderBy('views') defaults to false for the descending parameter if nothing is provided. So I'm not sure what was going on...but all is good now!

Comment: Hi @ckingprogramming, could you please post it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what explains the behavior, but if you remove the descending parameter after `orderBy`, it works. I'm not sure why the descending parameter was causing an issue.

`orderBy('views')` defaults to `false` for the descending parameter if nothing is provided anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `orderBy` prop in `getBy` function in https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-firestore-helper

You should be able to do something like:

```
db.getBy({ where: [{ city }, ['views' '>', -1]], orderBy: ['views', 'desc'] });
```

Then, in your code, get the first 5.

I'm not 100% sure about this, but the `limit` gets executed BEFORE the `orderBy`.

And that is a problem, because, again, as far as I remember (I may be wrong), Firebase will work as this:

- First, get ALL view > -1
- Then, get only the 5 first elements
- Finally, order the resulting 5 elements and retrieve them.

Again: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I remember having the same problem as you.

If somebody says I'm wrong, I'll remove this answer.

Check something here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Disclaimer: I am the creator of this library. It helps to manipulate objects in Firebase Firestore (and adds Cache)